# Grails 4: Not reading environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, grails-orm

In my Grails application running on Elastic Beanstalk, the DataSource URL is not defined in the app even though I've defined `dataSource.url` as an Environment Property in the software configuration in Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm running on `Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.7` using the embedded Tomcat Container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While this exact configuration works with the **EXTERNAL** Tomcat container, the **EMBEDDED** container seems to require environment variables are defined using all caps and underscores.
[image]